# How Can i open a subwindow with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I need to make a sub window using The pygame package, I want to do two type of subwindow, the first fixed in of the window and the second type completely independent of the window.

Answer (score 0):

While approaching this problem, be aware that two windows is pretty much impossible for Pygame, since it is dependent on SDL and SDL is limited to 1 screen.

Maayyybbe, you could run two different programs that have different windows and can interact with each other via some networking you set up. But at this point, you'd probably be better off coding in something else.

Making a sort of subwindow is doable by splitting up your screen, and to use parts of it for one thing, and others for something else. For example, you can blit images to this separate "window" that have totally different things going on than the stuff outside of it.

Also, please google before posting a question, a quick google search revealed [Pygame with Multiple Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811814/pygame-with-multiple-windows), which answers half of your question.