# Create multiple Pygame istance

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame

I'm trying to create a genetic algorithm that learns how to play Tetris.

But is there a way to creare multiple istance of the game?
So that i can create like 200 tetris, wait until all die and do operations instead of creating one instance, wait for the AI to lose, close the game, create a new one and so on?

I have tried with :

```
import logging
import threading
import time

from game import Game


def thread_function():
    Game()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=())
    x.start()
    y = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=())
    y.start()
    z = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=())
    z.start()
```

But the result is not 3 istances of the game, but only 1 with weirds thing going on.
If i use just one thread everything works fine.

Comment: No, all the variables that i'm using are attributes of the class

Comment: Instance attributes

Comment: See [Pygame with Multiple Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811814/pygame-with-multiple-windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually fixed the problem.

Instead of creating a single process and multithread, you have to create simple multi processes.

I have changed the code like this to get the points for each process created when terminated.

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
from game import Game


def thread_function(procnum, return_dict):
    return_dict[procnum] = Game().end_game()

processes = []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()

    for m in range(1, 3):
        p = Process(target=thread_function, args=(m, return_dict,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    print(return_dict.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

> But is there a way to create multiple instance of the game?

No, there is no way. See [`pygame.display`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) module:

> This module offers control over the pygame display. Pygame has a single display Surface that is either contained in a window or runs full screen. Once you create the display you treat it as a regular Surface. [...]

However, you don't need multiple windows at all. You can run the game logic multiple times concurrently. But display only one of them.