# How to distribute different functions by processes in a game written in Pygame?

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame, multiprocessing, game-engine

I'm writing a game using the pygame library in python. I want to write from scratch a serious enough project for which I may even write my own engine (all for educational purposes). And I faced one problem related to the speed of moving objects and more. I once thought that I would probably have to write code that would respond to a change in FPS in the game window. For example, I want to add to the game the ability to change the FPS. Also, the FPS may decrease if the computer does not have time to do all the calculations for the appropriate period of time.

Below is the code of my game, which I have greatly simplified. This code opens a window measuring 500x500 pixels, where you can move the square on a black background using the arrow keys on the keyboard. I did not write comments, because I think it is still clear how it works. The rendering () function refreshes the screen during each iteration of the main loop, drawing a square at x, y.
The event_check () function checks which keys the player has pressed and changes the values ​​of x and y. The mainloop () function starts the main cycle of the program, in which the event_check () and rendering () functions are started after the specified delay.

Now the cube moves very fast, because the delay on each iteration of the cycle is very small. The FPS value is 120, ie at each iteration the delay lasts 1/120 second. To reduce the speed of the cube, you can reduce the value of the variable speed or reduce the number of FPS. And this is the problem. If you set the FPS value to 60, the game will slow down twice. But FPS should only affect the screen refresh rate, not the game itself. In all normal 2D or 3D games and in game engines, objects always move at the speed that was prescribed, despite the FPS. And how do I also make sure that FPS does not affect the speed of objects in the game? Well, there is a solution, but I think we can do better. For example, at 120 FPS, if you hold down the right arrow key, we assume that the square overcomes a distance of 120 pixels in 1 second. Then at 60 FPS the speed should be twice as high, and at 30 in four, so that in 1 second the square overcomes the same distance, ie x + = speed * 120 / FPS and so on for all keys. But there is a problem. If the game has a lot of objects, you will need to do a lot of calculations, in addition, objects can not only move, but also change their size, as well as there is animation, etc. Such a large number of calculations would greatly slow down the game. That's why I don't like this method and I came up with another one, which I can't implement yet.

I thought. And what if you just create several loops that would work at the same time? In one cycle, events are checked, where, for example, 30 times per second during each iteration, the actions performed by the player are checked (keystrokes, mouse movements, etc.). And the values ​​always increase by pre-specified values, etc. That is, there is no redundant calculations and FPS has no effect there. But in another parallel running cycle, the screen is updated with the frequency that is specified in the FPS variable and the objects are moved according to the specified values. And in another cycle, some internal game events could be processed. And it should be much more efficient than when it's all calculated in one cycle. And I'm more than sure that everything works in modern game engines. And to try to implement it, I got acquainted with the modules threading and multiprocessing. I think that my problem can be solved with the help of multiprocessing, but I never managed to implement it. I'm still a beginner in this topic, but at least with the usual console programs, everything worked out for me, but I can't screw multiprocessing to the desktop program to solve the problem that I need. I tried to create 2 while-loops: one in function rendering (), and another in function event_check () and without function mainloop (). Next, I created two processes: one starts rendering, and the other runs event checking. And then launched them. But nothing worked. Three windows were launched instead of one and all of them were not working: 2 windows had just a black background, and the third had time to paint a square, but immediately froze. Also, the working decision should include the conditions of the race, because in my case one process reads the data and the other changes them.

I don't know how to solve this problem, so I ask you to rewrite my code and add multiprocessing so that everything works as I need. Or if you know another solution that would suit me, then show it to me. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()

win = pg.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pg.display.set_caption("Cubes Game")

x, y, width, height, speed, clock\
=\
50, 50, 50, 50, 5, pg.time.Clock()

def rendering():
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    pg.draw.rect(win, (0,0,255), (x, y, width, height))
    pg.display.update()
    pg.display.set_caption(str(clock.get_fps()))

def event_check():
    global run, x, y
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            exit()
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pg.K_LEFT] and x > 5:
        x -= speed
    if keys[pg.K_RIGHT] and x < 495 - width:
        x += speed
    if keys[pg.K_UP] and y > 5:
        y -= speed
    if keys[pg.K_DOWN] and y < 495 - width:
        y += speed

FPS = 120
run = True
def mainloop():
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        event_check()
        rendering()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Readers are going to miss the actual question if you write such long paragraphs. Please read on [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: *"Three windows were launched instead of one and all of them were not working: 2 windows had just a black background,"* Yes of course. Pygame doesn't support multiple windows and there is no workaround. See [Pygame with Multiple Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811814/pygame-with-multiple-windows).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you would have luck with asynchronous programming, multiple threads, or multiple processes (probably in that order). The goal is to have multiple contexts, each running at different time intervals. Here's a quick primer of each:

**Asynchronous Python**

Asynchronous processing can be a little hard to visualize. There's essentially a single thread of execution. Any time that thread waits, it switches to a new context, which then executes until the next 'wait.' The wait can be really general. In web development, it might be a HTTP GET request. In a game, it might be waiting for a timer to expire.

Here's a good primer: https://realpython.com/python-async-features/

The real benefit to this is that you get three separate 'contexts' (in this case, generators) without any of the gotchas of threads or the infrastructure behind multiple processes. However, it's probably going to be the slowest of the three. I'd suggest trying this first and only proceeding to the other two if it isn't fast enough.

**Multiple Threads**
Multi-threading is typically what is thought when multiple 'contexts' (in this case, a thread) run concurrently. All threads share the same memory space and a scheduler will determine which of the threads are given priority and executed at a given time.

Here's another RealPython link explaining threading: https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Note that threading has a lot of gotchas, specifically around which threads are prioritized, when the scheduler switches context, and sharing the same memory space. The uncontrolled switching of context and shared memory space can cause some nasty bugs which are very hard to find. Note that in Python this choice may only be slightly faster than asynchronous programming due to [some design choices with the language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock).

**Multiple Processes**
Using multiple processes will certainly be the fastest, but will require the most code. The difference between this and multiple threads is that the contexts (processes in this case) do not share the same memory space. You will need to find an interface to communicate between processes.

[Here's the RealPython primer](https://realpython.com/lessons/parallel-processing-multiprocessing-conclusion/)

**Game Architecture**
Now that we covered how to set up your 'contexts', you'll need to set up your game to use them. One example is the Model-View-Controller architecture. Here's a basic overview:

1. Model: maintains the state of the game (position of the square, player score, etc)
2. View: takes the model and renders it to the screen
3. Controller: takes player inputs and converts it to something the Model and View can use

The model, the view, and the controller will each be it's own 'context' (generator in asynchronous, thread in multi-threaded, or process in multi-process).

You could design your game such that the model wakes up every N number of microseconds and calculates the new position of the object using the difference between the current time and the last time the model woke up. Then, the view wakes at 120 FPS (for example) and just takes the last state of the model. Finally, the controller wakes whenever a player input is detected.

The real benefit of this approach is that if the View context falls behind and can only render 60 FPS, the model context is still churning away and updating the position of the object.

**Also Note**
You might have more luck asking your question more directly. Most of what was posted could be summarized with "How do I make sure that FPS does not affect the speed of objects in the game?" Then, post your example code with your question. The wall of text is intimidating :)

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you will be needing a delta time to properly adjust your movement speed based on FPS times.

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()

win = pg.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pg.display.set_caption("Cubes Game")

last_tick = 1

x, y, width, height, speed, clock = \
    50, 50, 50, 50, 100, pg.time.Clock()

def rendering():
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    pg.draw.rect(win, (0,0,255), (x, y, width, height))
    pg.display.update()
    pg.display.set_caption(str(clock.get_fps()))

def event_check():
    global run, x, y, last_tick

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            exit()
    
    delta_time = (pg.time.get_ticks() - last_tick) / 1000

    vel = speed * delta_time 

    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pg.K_LEFT] and x > 5:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pg.K_RIGHT] and x < 495 - width:
        x += vel
    if keys[pg.K_UP] and y > 5:
        y -= vel
    if keys[pg.K_DOWN] and y < 495 - width:
        y += vel
    

FPS = 60
run = True
def mainloop():
    global last_tick
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        event_check()
        rendering()
        last_tick = pg.time.get_ticks()

mainloop()
```

Great video explaining delta time : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuyrHE6GIsc