# Assosiate rects to specific window in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

in my program i defined main screen. The program will blit new window by clicking on different btn.

i want to undestand if it possible to define many windows and associate to them objects coordinates according the new windows locations.

in other words if it possible to edit "The beginning of the axes" for the object related to new window

for example:

- screen display is with width of 1000 and height of 800.
- new window with width,height = 800,800
- screen.blit(new_window,100,0)

> the new window will apeare from x0,y0 = 100,0 - x1,y1 = 900,800

- i want to create a rect in the new window but not according to screen cords but according to new_window cords where "The beginning of the axes" is the top left of that window.

i pasted the relavant lines for your review.

```
#before main loop start (this display updating by running in main loop)
screen = screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT))

# after main loop start when btn clicked on it
new_window= pygame.Surface((w,h))

#in main loop i use
screen.blit(new_window,(x,y))
```

if i create a new rect as

```
window_rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,w,h)
```

its define x,y coordinates for window_rect according to screen coords and not for new window. how can i associate new rects to new window?(so the new rect coordinate will be acording to new_window)

Note: i know that i can draw on that new window with:

```
pygame.draw.rect(new_window,color,(window_rect)
```

in that way it useing the new window coordinate for draw. but i need to define the rect according to new window for other functions

Comment: i think here is your soultion https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html

Comment: Nope . u sent me the draw methode. i noticed in my question that i can draw on it. but i cant define the rect coords according to new window. and i try to understand how to do it. thanks anyway

Comment: What do you mean by 'associate with the window' if you don't mean 'draw on the surface'?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @JeffUK 
i want to use that rect for colliders with other objecs (and for better understanding how to work with mulitple windows)

Comment: @bennyhassan you are making it very hard to understand your issue. `pygame.Surface()` is not a new *window*, but a `Surface` object used for representing images.

Comment: @bluevulture 
i just want to undestand if it possible to define many windows and associate to them objects coordinates according the new windows locations.

for example:
if the screen display is with width of 1000 and height of 800.
and i create new window start from x,y = 100,0 and with width,height = 800,800 so the new window will blit in x cord from 100 - 900 and y cord 0,800
my question is to understand if it possible to define new x,y according that new window so each object related to this window will blit according to new 0,0 (the top left of the new window)

Comment: @bennyhassan rectangles are just a data structure.  You can test collision of two rectangles entirely independently of drawing them on anything...  Why don't you make a start at writing something that does what you're trying to explain, and see where specifically you get stuck

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811814/pygame-with-multiple-windows

Comment: @Rabbid76 ,@JeffUK
anyway i edit my question according your comments and i hope now my misunderstaning is more clear . if still no i will try to open new question according JeffUK advise with new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to create a rect in the new window but not according to screen cords but according to new_window cords where "The beginning of the axes" is the top left of that window.

Unfortunately, there is no such feature in Pygame. You have to compute the window coordinates yourself. You can do this with [`pygame.Rect.move`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move).

e.g:: if you have a subwindow with the rectangle `sub_window_rect` and you have a rectangle inside the subwindow `rect_in_sub_window`:

```py
sub_window_rect = pygame.Rect(100, 0, 800, 800)
rect_in_sub_window = pygame.Rect(10, 10, 100, 100)

rect_in_window = rect_in_sub_window.move(*sub_window_rect.topleft)
```

The top left coordinate of `rect_in_window` is (110, 10).

Converting from window coordinated to subwindow coordinates:

```py
rect_in_sub_window = rect_in_window.move(
    -sub_window_rect.left, -sub_window_rect.top)
```